# Converting all letters in the phone number to digits

Tags: java

Im trying to replace each letter with a digit using the international standard letter/number mapping. I got my output to run correctly however, how do get the dashes in the phone number to appear automatically in the output? For example, if I enter 1800Flowers it prints out as 18003569377. How do I get it to print out as 1-800-3569377 without using regular expressions?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PhoneKeypad {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    //while loop keeps the program running until the user enters quit 
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("\nEnter a phone number or quit to exit:");
        String phoneNumber = input.next();

        if (phoneNumber.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")) {              
            System.out.print("\nProgrammed by me");
            return;
        }

        //checks if the phone number entered is at least 8 digits
        if (phoneNumber.length() < 8) {
            System.out.println("Invalid Phone Number");

        } else {

            System.out.println(getNumber(phoneNumber));
        }
    }

}

//method converts all letters in the phone number to digits
public static String getNumber(String phoneNumber) {

    int keypadNum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < phoneNumber.length(); i++) {
        char letter = phoneNumber.charAt(i);

        if (Character.isAlphabetic(letter)) {
            letter = Character.toUpperCase(letter);

            switch (letter) {
                case 'A':
                case 'B':
                case 'C':
                    keypadNum = 2;
                    break;
                case 'D':
                case 'E':
                case 'F':
                    keypadNum = 3;
                    break;
                case 'G':
                case 'H':
                case 'I':
                    keypadNum = 4;
                    break;
                case 'J':
                case 'K':
                case 'L':
                    keypadNum = 5;
                    break;
                case 'M':
                case 'N':
                case 'O':
                    keypadNum = 6;
                    break;
                case 'P':
                case 'Q':
                case 'R':
                case 'S':
                    keypadNum = 7;
                    break;
                case 'T':
                case 'U':
                case 'V':
                    keypadNum = 8;
                    break;
                case 'W':
                case 'X':
                case 'Y':
                case 'Z':
                    keypadNum = 9;
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Invalid phone number");
            }

            phoneNumber = phoneNumber.substring(0, i) + keypadNum + phoneNumber.substring(i + 1);
        }
    }

    return phoneNumber;
}
}
```

Expected Output:
[image: Output]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a *regular expression* with `String.replaceAll`. Remove the leading one, group the first three digits, the second three digits and the final group of digits. Something like

```
public static String formatNumber(String phoneNumber) {
    if (phoneNumber.startsWith("1")) {
        phoneNumber = phoneNumber.substring(1);
    }
    return phoneNumber.replaceAll("(\\d{3})(\\d{3})(\\d+)", "1-$1-$2-$3");
}
```

**or**

```
public static String formatNumber(String phoneNumber) {
    return phoneNumber.replaceAll("1(\\d{3})(\\d{3})(\\d+)", "1-$1-$2-$3");
}
```

And then call it like

```
System.out.println(formatNumber(getNumber(phoneNumber)));
```

I ran it with `1800flowers` and got (as expected)

> 1-800-356-9377

**or** without regular expressions like

```
public static String formatNumber(String phoneNumber) {
    if (phoneNumber.startsWith("1")) {
        phoneNumber = phoneNumber.substring(1);
    }
    return "1-".concat(phoneNumber.substring(0, 3)) //
            .concat("-").concat(phoneNumber.substring(3, 6)) //
            .concat("-").concat(phoneNumber.substring(6));
}
```

Before calling `formatNumber`, you can remove the dashes to *normalize* it with something like

```
public static String removeDashes(String phoneNumber) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (char ch : phoneNumber.toCharArray()) {
        if (ch != '-') {
            sb.append(ch);
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Then

```
System.out.println(formatNumber(removeDashes(getNumber(phoneNumber))));
```

Comment: How would I do that without regular expressions?

Comment: Why do that `startsWith("1")` and `substring(1)`? Why not just add `1?` to beginning of regex? Also, shouldn't the last one be `(\\d{4})\\d*`, so any excessive digits are discarded?

Comment: @Andreas Good point. There's a lot of ways you could do it. OP has a check on the `phoneNumber` length. So it should be safe.

Comment: For non-regex, why `concat` instead of `+`?

Comment: @Andreas I prefer a more fluent style when available.

Comment: You think `a.concat(b).concat(String.valueOf(c)).concat(d)` is more fluent than `a + b + c + d`? Matter of style, I guess?

Comment: @Andreas Which is easier to reason about (in terms of what it **actually** does) in Java?

Comment: Sorry I am new to java but how would `+` be used instead of `concat`?

Comment: @ally `return "1-" + phoneNumber.substring(0, 3) + "-" + phoneNumber.substring(3, 6) + "-" + phoneNumber.substring(6);`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I noticed that when I enter 1-800-Flowers, the output returns 1--80-0-3-569377, how would I get it to return 1-800-3569377? In short, I wanted the user to be able to enter input with or without dashes and the output would remain in this format: 1-800-3569377

Comment: Remove the `-`(s).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch tried that but again I wanted to give the user a choice of _entering a number with or without dashes_ but **I want the output to show dashes**. When I remove the "-", the dashes disappear entirely :(

Comment: Remove the dashes from `phoneNumber` before formatting it.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch `return "1" + phoneNumber.substring(0, 3) + phoneNumber.substring(3, 6) + phoneNumber.substring(6);` like this?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I added the expected output in my first post, I'm having trouble matching the first and third output

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Thank you for the edits! I assume that it's better to have these in separate methods like what you did?

Comment: @ally "Better" is frequently subjective. I prefer to separate concerns and aim for easy to read code. However, when dealing with code, it may be necessary to optimize for speed (or size). In which case the definition of "better" becomes less subjective.